# Try to get UITextField from subviews, but getting UITextfieldLabel

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a view contain multiple UITextField.
So when keyboard pop up I loop through the view to find out which textfield is first responder.

I try to print out all the view class, it show UITextFieldLabel instead of UITextField, anyone know what is this? I want to find out which textfiled getting focus.

Here is the code I use.

```
extension UIView{

    func firstResponder() -> UIView?{
        if self.isFirstResponder()
        {
            return self
        }

        for  view in self.subviews
        {

            if view.isFirstResponder()
            {
                return view
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code that you are using

Comment: Ya, I just edit my question

Answer (score 0):

`UITextField` has a protocol to which your view can conform to. When a textfield is selected or edited, you will get that textfield in your delegate method.

```
class myView: UIView, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var anExampleTextField: UITextField?         

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame);
        self.anExampleTextField.delegate = self
    }

    //if using interface builder
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.anExampleTextField.delegate = self
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        //The selected textfield will be passed here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what I trying to do is, I have a custom view controller which observer keyboard event, so when keyboard show, it will get textfield which is first responder, then move the view according textfield position. But what i get is UITextFieldLabel not UITextField. I have no idea why